# How to create a own pagination for observable data?

Tags: angular

I have a observable data that is iterated inside loop:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="features$ | async as data; else nodata">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data.layers"></ng-container>
    <app-pagination ></app-pagination>
</ng-container>
```

The `features$` is filled by static variable:

```
features$.next({layers: {4: [], 3:[]}});
```

So, I change the value like:

```
let changes = features$.getValue();
chnages[4].push("new");
features$.next(changes);
```

This way rerenders the whole template, including the changes. It is fit for me.
But problem is I can not store the state of pagination if user used.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using some sort of state solution, you can just pass the index the user selected as its own action and store in your store.

Ex:

//Your Action Types Here

`IndexChange : '[YourFeatureName] Index Changed`

//Your actual actions

```
IndexChange implements Action {
   readonly type = YourActionTypes.IndexChange;
   constructor(public payload: number) {}
```

//Your reducer:
...

```
case(YourActionTypes.IndexChange) 
{
   state = {
     ...state,
     userIndex: action.payload
   };

   break;
}
...

return state;
```

//Then you can create a selector which listens to that piece of your state and you can subscribe to it in your component. Further reading: https://ngrx.io/guide/store

Edit

A more straight forward solution would be to use local/session storage as well. https://medium.com/@nixonaugustine5/localstorage-and-sessionstorage-in-angular-app-65cda19283a0

So big picture is that it is a key-value pair dictionary (or map if you prefer). So you would just do something like:

```
localStorage.setItem(‘UserIndex’, indexNumber);
```

and then in order to get it you would do:

```
let userIndex = localStorage.getItem(‘UserIndex’);
```

This way you can store what index your user has selected.